# Do arXiv links last for the forseeable future?

Tags: everyday-life

If I give someone an arXiv link, say http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.0118 , will this link last for the foreseeable future?

Comment: Suggest migration: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Can you do it (please)? I can't do **** with 3 rep.

Comment: If this is to be migrated anywhere, [academia.SE] is probably the place for it...

Comment: It's 2023 and you can still access arxiv papers from 1991, e.g. https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.hep-th/9109051 (maybe the DOI link is better than the "abstract" one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The software doesn't allow less than 30 characters so...

Comment: Cheeeeeeeeeers.

Comment: you can always use 30 characters to provide a cite/prove link if you know one :-)